# Finding the group bundle associated to a $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]$ module

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, principal-bundles

I am trying to understand twisted coefficients better, because although I technically know the definitions both using modules and group bundles, my intution of the subject doesn't really exist yet. To this end I wanted to understand the groups $H_i(S^1, \mathbb{Z}[t])$ where a generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ by multiplication by $t$.

Now I know I can just perform the computation because we can find a very agreeable cell structure on the universal cover of $S^1$ and then work on the complex $C_*(\mathbb{R})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]}\mathbb{Z}[t]$. But this doesn't satisfy me from an intuitive point of view.

So my question is, is it possible to describe a $\mathbb{Z}$-bundle $E\to S^1$ such that $H_i(S^1, E)\cong H_i(S^1, \mathbb{Z}[t])$? I tried finding some product or disjoint union of the universal cover, but didn't find anything.

Thankss

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for your answer. I don't see how smoothness appears though? Wouldn't it just be continuous functions. Admitting this (perhaps simply by restricting), how do I see that your example provides the desired outcome?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez i think there must be some confusion as to the context... The category in which I am working is Top, following Hatcher's definition of bundle from his algebraic topology book section 3.H. So to my understanding there is no obvious reason for the functions to be differentiable at all

Comment: Ah alright, so there is indeed a restriction to smooth functions